# jQuery ajax method doesn't pass post data key when using anonymous function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have tried to send one of the key to data parameter as anonymous function, but whatever datatype it returns, Jquery doesn't pass it to server.

**Examples:**

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'http://host.com/cart',
    dataType: 'html',
    data: {
        'quantity': function () {
            var return_obj = [];
            return_obj['1:YTowOnt9'] = '1';
            return return_obj;
        },
        'action': 'cart-update-quantity'
    },
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

this has the `action` POST key, however `quantity` key is empty string. I tried also as string and object.

This example is working:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'http://host.com/cart',
    dataType: 'html',
    data: {
        'quantity': {
            '1:YTowOnt9': '1'
        },
        'action': 'cart-update-quantity'
    },
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

How can I send anonymous function to `quantity` key in data? The anonymous function will get some of the form inputs dinamically. I also have tried jQuery `serializeArray`, but it send the data wrong.

Comment: Why do you want to put a function there? Just pass a dynamic object that is built before the `ajax` call.

Comment: [Don't abuse arrays!](http://andrewdupont.net/2006/05/18/javascript-associative-arrays-considered-harmful/) Especially jQuery will choke on that.

Comment: @Bergi: Thanks for pointing that out. For me, `Array.length` equals zero to non number keys is a big point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not need to defer execution of the anonymous function, so just call it immediately to return your object:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'http://host.com/cart',
    dataType: 'html',
    data: {
        'quantity': (function () {
            var return_obj = {};
            return_obj['1:YTowOnt9'] = '1';
            return return_obj;
        })(),
        'action': 'cart-update-quantity'
    },
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

This is called an IIFE (immediately Invoked function expression).

Alternatively, just build the object before the Ajax call.. In any case the error was down to passing a function and not the result of the function.

*Note: This code includes an edit by `Bergi` to create an object (with `{}`) instead of an array (with `[]`)

You can of course simply that IIFE to an anonymous object declaration:

```
'quantity': (function () {
        return {'1:YTowOnt9': '1'};
    })(),
```

Comment: Your code functioned right away. I also found [this](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/function-as-parameter-data-in-ajax-requests#14737000002810204) as the same example. I was thinking that self invoked functions will invoke themselves only once. However having the ajax in a function will invoke the IIFE every time I invoke the main function, correct?

Comment: Self invoked functions get called based on where they are. If in a loop or function they get called each time. You often see them as globals in which case they only get called once. Cheers.